# 301 rewrite in .htaccess for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to convert all traffic from my old sub domains to just the root domain but not having any luck. For instance www.australia.example.com, australia.example.com and www.australia.example.com/sub-directory would all go to example.com.

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(australia|canada|china|germany|hongkong|indonesia|italy|malaysia|newzealand|southafrica|southkorea|switzerland|thailand|uk|usa)\.example\.com$ [NC]     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There technically isn't anything wrong with the rule except you need a `/` in the rewrite rule `http://example.com/$1` Are all these subdomains on the same sever?

Comment: yep, they are all the same server and same domain. I just got rid of all the sub sites so I want everything to just go to the root

Comment: @PanamaJack as a side note, I added that `/` and it is not working. The old  `www.australia.example.com` still loads. No redirect.